# How to configure Nginx for a VPS?

Tags: nginx, docker, vps, shared-hosting

I just upgraded my shared hosting to a VPS (both on hostinger), the VPS has 2 vCPUs and 8GB Ram (Shared hosting had 2vCPUs and less Ram), always below 5% CPU usage & 25% Ram usage.

However, the VPS is much slower than the shared hosting. It takes at least 2 times longer on the VPS to resolve a single request.

Shared hosting:
[image: it takes 636ms to resolve]

VPS:
[image: it takes 1670ms to resolve]

That is my current Nginx script - nginx.conf (exists in the laravel app docker image)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;

    root /var/www/html/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        # include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Also, when opening the app that talks to the server, it feels like it resolves one request at a time, a couple of requests (loading the home page), takes 20 seconds to finish, everytime.
On the shared hosting it wasn't more than 2 seconds.

I am using cloudflare on both (VPS and Hostinger).

Also, my server got 4 docker images.

1. nginx:latest
2. Laravel app (the one that has the nginx.conf)
3. SQL instance
4. phpmyadmin

Any help would be so much appreciated, as I am in prod and it's a complete nightmare.
Thanks!

Comment: You have 3 components (nginx/app/DB) and underlying OS that all affect the performance and you provide information about only nginx, which is the one that is the least likely to be a bottleneck.  You are looking under a lamppost.

Comment: I have the same website on a shared hosting plan. It is working very fast. I recently edited the nginx.conf file and updated www record to point to hostinger cdn, now any request to www. subdomain resolves under ~300ms, but to the main domain, it takes 1200ms.

Comment: What about caching? Maybe the shared hosting is caching results and the backend system is slow. There is no caching turned on in your nginx conf.